# Perform search operation and save some data from the text following it, in ruby if possible

Tags: ruby, regex, string, full-text-search

There is a text document containing this text.

```
---random data---
==String_1==
{{item_1
    | name= name_1 | url=url_1 | email= email_1 | address= |
}}
---random data---
```

Now, I want that whenever String_1 is encountered, all the fields (name, url, email and address) as strings in a Hash named item_1.
Ruby code is preferred.

Comment: Is the information you want guaranteed to be the second line after the one containing `"String_1"`?

Comment: Yup, nothing in between. Just values change, not the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it, though I don't quite understand what you mean by wanting to save the results in a hash named `item1`. I have saved the results in an array of hashes.  I presume you can adjust this to your requirements.  (My apologies for the horizontal scrolling--I try to avoid the need for that.)

**Code**

```
KEYS = %w{ name url email address }
def pull_vals(fname)
    enum = File.readlines(fname).to_enum
    arr = []
    r = /\s*\|\s*name=\s*(\S*)\s*\|\s*url=\s*(\S*)\s*\|\s*email=\s*(\S*)\s*\|\s*address=\s*(\S*)\s*\|/
    loop do
      next unless enum.next =~ /==String_1==/
      enum.next
      arr << KEYS.zip(enum.next.scan(r).flatten(1)).to_h
    end
    arr
end
```

**Example**

```
text =<<_
---random data---
==String_1==
{{item_1
    | name= name_1 | url=url_1 | email= email_1 | address= |
}}
---random data---
==String_1==
{{item_2
    | name= name_2 | url=url_2 | email= email_2 | address= home |
}}
_

FNAME = "my_file"
File.write(FNAME, text)

pull_vals(FNAME)
  #=> [{"name"=>"name_1", "url"=>"url_1", "email"=>"email_1", "address"=>""},
  #    {"name"=>"name_2", "url"=>"url_2", "email"=>"email_2", "address"=>"home"}]
```

When, as in this case, the regex pattern is repetitious, it may be easiest to get it working for one part of the string, then use a bit of code to form the regex:

```
Regexp.new (KEYS.map {|str| "\\s*\\|\\s*#{str}=\\s*(\\S*)"} << "\\s*\\|").join
```

Answer (score 0):

With this pattern you can extract all the values you need that are inside named captures:

```
/(?: ==String_1== \s+ {{ (?<name> \S+ ) | (?!\A)\G )  # entry point
 \s* \| \s*
 (?<key>   [^\s=]+ ) \s* = \s* 
 (?<value> [^|}]+? ) (?=\s*[|}]) # the lookahead is used to enforce the lazy
                                 # quantifier to take all the value until an
                                 # optional trailing space before a pipe or a 
                                 # closing curly bracket
/x
```

It's a little a general pattern that isn't probably the most appropriate to your specific case, but you are free to adapt it or to use ideas from it to build your own.